# bullet euler angle methods

Tags: ros, bullet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly are the differences between:

- getEulerZYX/setEulerZYX
- getEulerYPR/setEulerYPR
- getRPY/setRPY

EDIT: I'm looking at bullet (and the ROS patches).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9541/bullet-euler-angle-methods/) by [tperkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/124/tperkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-03-23**:
Which library/set of code are you using?  Is this for bullet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These were discussed in this [meeting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Reviews/Euler_Angle_Usage_2009-09-02_API_Review)

The methods are documented in the headers.  However, I see the doxygen docs are not generating correctly at the moment so I'll copy them here:

**get/setRPY is recommended**

```
  /**@brief Set the quaternion using fixed axis RPY
   * @param roll Angle around X 
   * @param pitch Angle around Y
   * @param yaw Angle around Z*/
  void setRPY(const btScalar& roll, const btScalar& pitch, const btScalar& yaw)
```

get/setEuler is defined as follows:

```
  /**@brief Set the quaternion using Euler angles
   * @param yaw Angle around Y
   * @param pitch Angle around X
   * @param roll Angle around Z */
    void setEuler(const btScalar& yaw, const btScalar& pitch, const btScalar& roll)
```

**get/setEulerZYX is deprecated due to being ambiguous in different implementations:**

```
  /**@brief Set the quaternion using euler angles 
   * @param yaw Angle around Z
   * @param pitch Angle around Y
   * @param roll Angle around X */
  void setEulerZYX(const btScalar& yaw, const btScalar& pitch, const btScalar& roll) __attribute__((deprecated))
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-23**:
Bullet natively uses a different convention for yaw pitch and roll.  The difference between fixed axis and euler angles are defined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Euler_angles_as_composition_of_extrinsic_rotations

**Comment by [tperkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/124/tperkins/) on 2011-03-23**:
I'm not sure I understand the difference between fixed-axis rotation and Euler angles. Is different from R(θ) = Rx(θ) * Ry(θ) * Rz(θ)? Also, what's the convention for get/setEuler? YXZ? Is pitch really around the x axis? I thought it was the y axis...